# What is the difference between the script tag and the writing system tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have both a [script](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) tag and a [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system) tag.

The description of [script](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) reads

> Questions about (learning) scripts or writing systems, i.e. the visual
>   representation of verbal communication. This includes alphabets,
>   abjads, abugidas, logographic systems, etc.

The description of [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system) reads

> A writing system is a set of symbols used to represent a language in
>   writing. A writing system can be representative of various sounds
>   (cenemic), of various meanings (pleremic), or both.

[script](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) currently has three questions; [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system) has 15 questions. In spite of the different definitions, I think they can be merged, or **[script](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) can be made a synonym of [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system)**. Since "script" can also have other meanings, such as manuscript or screenplay, I'd rather make "script" a synonym for "writing system" than the other way around.

What do others think?

**Update 08.09.2017**: [script](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) is now a synonym of [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system).

Comment: I don't have the reputation in the [writing-system] tag to make it a tag synonym, so I've pinged the moderators in chat.

Comment: @fi12 I have [suggested a synonym](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/tags/writing-system/synonyms) now, and people can vote for it.

Comment: Great. I don't have the rep in that tag to vote for it, so I think we'll have to wait for other users.

Comment: I believe the privilege to vote for tag synonyms doesn't come from total reputation. Instead, you can vote for tag synonyms in a specific tag if you have a total answer score of 5 or more in that tag, regardless of total reputation.

Comment: I assume you have posted many upvoted answers on questions with the writing-system tag.

Comment: @fi12 I am listed as "top answerer" for both 'writing-system' and 'script'. Thay may be the explanation.

Comment: @AnthonyPham I am not aware of the concept of subtags; there was a rejected feature request for it on Meta SE. If script is intended (informally) as a subtag, this should be much clearer from the definitions. I still see them as synonyms, though.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Well, let me rephrase my comment (my grace period disappeared): as script seems to be a sub-tag of writing systems but  sub-tags are not allowed, script should then be a synonym of writing-systems

Comment: @AnthonyPham The synonym has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning, and after looking at the questions using these tags, [script](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) should be made a synonym of [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system).